# how to store the result of plt.bar into an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I want to know of it's possible to store the result of the plt.bar function into an array. Something like

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[21321,5345,654457]

height=list(b)

plt.bar(a,height=height)

a_b=result_of_pltbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by storing the result into an array, but here are some thoughts.

Assuming that the `plt` is imported by `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` the resulting figure looks like this:

[image: barplot]

- The heights of the bars are in `b`
- The x-positions of the bars are stored in `a`

Now you have everyting else but the "edges" of the bars. To get the current axis you may use `ax = plt.gca()`. If you investigate `vars(ax)` you'll see that `ax.patches` looks particularly interesting. They contain data about the bars. Here is what you will find from the `ax.patches[0]`:

```
In [18]: vars(ax.patches[0])
Out[18]:
{'_stale': True,
....
 '_x0': 0.6,
 '_y0': 0,
 '_width': 0.8,
 '_height': 21321,
 '_x1': 1.4,
 '_y1': 21321,
....
}
```

From here it is easy to see that these are all the geometric properties and position coordinates for the first bar. So, if you would like to collect the left edges of the bars, you would use

```
left_edges = [bar._x0 for bar in ax.patches]
```

which will result into `[0.6, 1.6, 2.6]`. The process of getting other properties of the bars should be clear.